# Term for someone who leaves a relationship after the other person buys them a bunch of stuff

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

I'm looking for the proper term.

So there's a female. Her name is Kaylee. Knows this guy that is madly in love with her and would give anything to be with her. Well, she is struggling and needs things for her kids and wants things herself. This guy and her always talk and it seems like (as she makes it seem) like they are gunna get together. And he starts buying her everything she needs like her kids Christmas her a phone and just everything she asks for. Well one day Kaylee meets up with her ex-boyfriend (baby daddy) and all the sudden just drops Tom like nothing and pretty much says (without actually saying it) "thanks for buying all this stuff but bye."

I know there's a word or phrase for it. But it's like making someone think they're gunna be together and whatnot then leaving after the other person buys them a bunch of stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Consider ***[leech](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leech)***:

> a person who clings to another for personal gain, especially without giving anything in return, and usually with the implication or effect of exhausting the other's resources; parasite.

Or(e) colloquially, ***[gold-digger](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gold-digger?s=t)***:

> a woman who associates with or marries a man chiefly for material gain.

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: +1 Good suggestions. I don't know why your answer was voted down.

Comment: @ChrisSunami I think the answer has been edited but you are right. I would keep that in mind the next time.

Comment: I chose to remove parasite since it's in leech's definition.